# How come there's no "To" field for the "Send & Wait For Reply" widget in the Twilio Studio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I'm trying to create a Studio flow that is triggered by a REST API request to then prompt a recipient to respond Yes or No to a question. However, unlike the "Send Message" widget, the "Send & Wait For Reply" widget doesn't have a "SEND MESSAGE TO" field that I can configure.

How am I supposed to use this widget to send a message to a particular contact if I can't configure that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you kick off the REST API trigger, you pass in the From and To ( `contact.channel.address`) and that is used in this case.

[Trigger a Twilio Studio Flow Execution via the REST API](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007778153-Trigger-a-Twilio-Studio-Flow-Execution-via-the-REST-API)

[Execution](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution)

Comment: Thanks @Alan! Tested this and it works. QQ - any idea why the "Send" widget allows for this to be configured at the widget level but this one does not?

Comment: Hi Yohannes, excellent question, Studio maintains a session to keep track of the conversation in an execution, and that session is based on the To/From. if the developer changes the "To" to some other number midway through, studio can't match replies from the new number to the current session. The send widget is fire and forget, so no session tracking is needed for the "to" number.